# Is it possible to Favorite / Bookmark an Answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers

I know that we can favorite / bookmark a Question which is very useful for me as I can go back to that quickly from my profile.

But is it possible to Favorite an Answer the same way ? If a question has multiple answers, its not always the accepted answer is the best one, so if i want to pick one i like for future reference, I can mark that as my favorite answer.

is it possible now ? I couldn't find anything in the FAQ / help centre around this. if its not currently possible, can this be added as a feature request somehow ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to do that.  It has been asked for on meta.stackexchage.com:

[Is there any way to favorite/bookmark an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer)

There are a couple of suggestions in the answers (paraphrasing):

- Favorite the question and remember which answer is the one you like, which would almost always be the one with the most votes.
- Bookmark the link to the answer (e.g., [this](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/736/is-it-possible-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer/737#737)). You can get the link to bookmark by clicking the `share` short permalink.

Comment: thanks @peter-knolle .. the bookmark link is handy

Comment: Very helpful Peter & something I'll be able to use as well! Took me a couple of minutes to figure out that the `share` button was the source of the link attribute to the answer.

Comment: @crmprogdev - I updated the answer to add that. Thanks for pointing it out. :)